# prototype for `' does not match any in class `'

Tags: c++

I've got problem while compilling my program:

> prototype for int SROMemory::ReadString(unsigned int) does not match any in class SROMemory

Whats going on?

Here's a link to my Dev C++ project:  https://www.sendspace.com/file/uop8m8

```
#include "memory.h"

SROMemory::SROMemory()
{
          GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(NULL, (LPCSTR)TEXT("Tibia")), &PROC_ID);
          PROC_HANDLE = OpenProcess(0x10, false, PROC_ID);
}

int SROMemory::ReadString(unsigned int Pointer)
{
        char cValue[24] = "\0";
        ReadProcessMemory(PROC_HANDLE, (LPVOID)Pointer, &cValue, sizeof(cValue), NULL);
        string Value = cValue;
        return Value;
}
```

this is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "memory.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     bool exit = false;

     SROMemory Memory;

     string loginPass = Memory.ReadString(0x78F554);

     cout << "LoginPass: " << loginPass << "\n";

     do
     {

     }while(!exit);
}
```

and this is memory.cpp:

```
#include "memory.h"

SROMemory::SROMemory()
{
          GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindow(NULL, (LPCSTR)TEXT("Tibia")), &PROC_ID);
          PROC_HANDLE = OpenProcess(0x10, false, PROC_ID);
}

int SROMemory::ReadString(unsigned int Pointer)
{
        char cValue[24] = "\0";
        ReadProcessMemory(PROC_HANDLE, (LPVOID)Pointer, &cValue, sizeof(cValue), NULL);
        string Value = cValue;
        return Value;
}
```

Yup and i forgot about memory.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class SROMemory
{
    public:
        SROMemory();
        int ReadPointer(unsigned int Pointer);
        int ReadOffset(unsigned int Offset);
        string ReadString(unsigned int Pointer);
    private:
        DWORD PROC_ID;
        HANDLE PROC_HANDLE;
};
```

Comment: the link is .dev file, please post your code directly here

Comment: Don't post your program. Post a minimal self-contained code sample that reproduces the problem. Or read the compiler error carefully and think about what it is trying to tell you.

Comment: You need to look closely at the header that contains the class declaration for SROMemory. That declaration doesn't have something that matches the SROMemory::ReadString you're defining in the .cpp file.

Comment: Your member function returns `string` in header file and `int` in cpp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function signature (in the source file) doesn't match the signature of the prototype (declaration in header): change the following line in your source file:

```
int SROMemory::ReadString(unsigned int Pointer)
```

to

```
string SROMemory::ReadString(unsigned int Pointer)
```

another possibility according to [Prototype... does not match any in Class... (error). g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252069/prototype-does-not-match-any-in-class-error-g) is, that your source file includes the wrong header file

Comment: I think that i'm editing the right files

Comment: please also provide us with the contents of your headers, i.e. is SROMemory really declaring a function int ReadString(unsigned int)?

Comment: They are now in the main post

Comment: No, you still haven't provided memory.h.

Comment: are you sure your ReadString returns an int? according to your use in main.cpp you expect a string...

Comment: because it should be a string

Comment: yup i forgot about memory.h-> now in main post

Comment: there's your problem then: mismatching return type (string in header, int in source file)... can you accept my answer please?

Comment: sry i don't understand... can you show me this in code?